# Trying to end goroutine using close(ch) but end up running infinitely

Tags: go

I am trying to end multiple goroutines once another goroutine closes a channel. However, I am ending up into infinite loop after close signal is received. I can't figure out why.

I know that it is possible using context.Context but I was trying out by closing channels.

Go Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/C6pcYgGLnG9

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "sync"
)


func runner(id int, ch <-chan struct{}, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    for {
        select {
            case <-time.Tick(time.Second):
                fmt.Println("worker ", id)
            case <- ch:
                fmt.Println("closing worker ", id)
                break
        }
    }

    wg.Done()

}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    ch := make(chan struct{})
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    wg.Add(1)
    go runner(1, ch, &wg)

    wg.Add(1)
    go runner(2, ch, &wg)

    time.Sleep(5*time.Second)

    close(ch)

    wg.Wait()
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the scope of your `break`:

```
func runner(id int, ch <-chan struct{}, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    for {
        select {
            case <-time.Tick(time.Second):
                fmt.Println("worker ", id)
            case <- ch:
                fmt.Println("closing worker ", id)
                break
        }
    }

    wg.Done()
}
```

You want to break out of the for loop, but you're actually only breaking out of the `select`.  To remedy this, you have two choices:

1. Add a label to your for loop, and break from it explicitly:

   ```
   func runner(id int, ch <-chan struct{}, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
   loop:  // <---------- add a label
       for {
           select {
           case <-time.Tick(time.Second):
               fmt.Println("worker ", id)
           case <-ch:
               fmt.Println("closing worker ", id)
               break loop  // <---------- and break from it explicitly
           }
       }

       wg.Done()
   }
   ```
2. Probably a more idiomatic and robust solution, simply return when you're done. This means the `wg.Done()` call must be deferred.

   ```
   func runner(id int, ch <-chan struct{}, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
       defer wg.Done() // <--- Defer the wg.Done() call, so it happens on return
       for {
           select {
           case <-time.Tick(time.Second):
               fmt.Println("worker ", id)
           case <-ch:
               fmt.Println("closing worker ", id)
               return   // <--- replace `break` with `return`
           }
       }
   }
   ```